# How to use leaflet.js with react-native

Tags: android, react-native, leaflet

I am having a difficult time setting up `Leaflet.js` with `react-native`. The documentation tells me to add the following script in my html...

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

But I am not sure how I do this using react. Right now my main page is being rendered as follows...

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('beacon', () => Home);
```

And my `Home` is simply something like...

```
export default Home = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MainMap />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Where/How do I add this script tag to include `Leaflet.js`? Is it even possible? Is there perhaps another solution?

I haven't seen any examples of `react-native` and `Leaflet.js`, if there is one, on github or what not, I'd be happy to see it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a project [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) through which you can use leaflet.js with react.

But currently there is **no support** for using leaflet.js in react-native. See this [issue](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/26) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

There is one project I found online that addresses leaflet with React Native: https://github.com/reggie3/react-native-webview-leaflet

Comment: Do you know is there any performance penalty for using this instead of `react-native-maps`? I want to use this with `openstreetmap` data.

Comment: I ended up using react-native-maps, despite this shortcoming, as otherwise I had problems due to the fact that it's a webview and not a native component.

Comment: This project is deprecated because no longer maintained. This one is said to be the most recent and up to date : https://github.com/pavel-corsaghin/react-native-leaflet

Answer (score 5):

Please check this out [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) recommended by react native

Comment: yeah I ended up going with this

Comment: It's a good answer, although not good enough if you were looking for a map API compatible with React Native that uses Open Street Map data.

react-native-maps uses Apple Maps and Google Maps.

Comment: We don't want to pay to Google. $200 free tier is not enough.

Comment: use https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps instead - uses mapbox

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use leftlet you can host it on website and use react native webview to run in you can sent data between app and web via postMessage function of webview but performance is not good though compare to react native map but atleat you can use bunch of leftlet plugin